# Constructing an array from db response using async await in node

Tags: node.js, sqlite, async-await

I'm trying to construct an array of database responses using the async await syntax.

I understand that since async await is just a way of wrapping promises in nicer syntax, it should be easy to convert the promise-oriented instructions given [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/connect/) into that format.

Here's what I have:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")


async function getDB(dbname) {
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(dbname)
    return db;
}

app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    let db = await getDB(dbname)
    let r = await db.serialize(() => {
        let results = []
        db.each(`SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 3`, (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
            }
            let m = row.id;
            console.log(m);
            results.push(m)
            });
        return results
    });
    res.send(await r)
})

app.listen(port, ipaddr);
```

When I call this, the response is:

```
{"open":false,"filename":"dbname.db","mode":65542}
```

but I expect:

```
[1,2,3]
```

What's happening and how do I fix it?

In the console, I can see the records are being retrieved:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]  # this is exactly the thing I want returned!  Why can't I retrieve it?
```

So I know the database call actually works, but I can't seem to get them /into/ any object I can get out of the await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [sqlite package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite), rather than the [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) used in the demo.  It has better support for async await.